# How to scan and ip range in nmap

Tags: networking, ip, nmap

I've been using **Angry IP Scanner** and with that, I easily could scan an IP range by putting starting IP and ending IP in two text boxes.
Now in **nmap**, I want to know how to scan an IP range with giving two IPs: staring IP and ending IP. For example, I like to use nmap like this:

```
nmap 10.10.10.10 10.10.15.254.254
```

NOTE THAT I DON'T WANT TO USE THAT /24 IN THE END OF THE IP.

Comment: Read `man nmap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man nmap`

> ```
>    CIDR notation is short but not always flexible enough. For example, you
>    might want to scan 192.168.0.0/16 but skip any IPs ending with .0 or
>    .255 because they may be used as subnet network and broadcast
>    addresses. Nmap supports this through octet range addressing. Rather
>    than specify a normal IP address, you can specify a comma-separated
>    list of numbers or ranges for each octet. For example,
>    192.168.0-255.1-254 will skip all addresses in the range that end in .0
>    or .255, and 192.168.3-5,7.1 will scan the four addresses 192.168.3.1,
>    192.168.4.1, 192.168.5.1, and 192.168.7.1. Either side of a range may
>    be omitted; the default values are 0 on the left and 255 on the right.
>    Using - by itself is the same as 0-255, but remember to use 0- in the
>    first octet so the target specification doesn't look like a
>    command-line option. Ranges need not be limited to the final octets:
>    the specifier 0-255.0-255.13.37 will perform an Internet-wide scan for
>    all IP addresses ending in 13.37. This sort of broad sampling can be
>    useful for Internet surveys and research.
> ```

So you will need to figure out what your starting and ending range is.  From what I can see it looks like you are doing `10.10.10.10` thru `10.10.15.254` (your ending IP of `10.10.15.254.254` is an invalid address), but that covers 6 entire subnets and each subnet starts with a .1 and ends with a .254 IP, so you probably don't want to start each subnet at .10 as you will skip the first 9 IPs of each subnet.  So, do it this way:  (I have added a -(s)can command and search for hosts that (n)o-port-scan (formerly -sP) which will scan 1,524 IP addresses)

```
nmap -sn 10.10.10-15.1-254
```

But from what you wrote, that is what I think you want.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Exactly right. But `-sP` was renamed `-sn` over 10 years ago to be more clear of its meaning: skip the port scan phase. This leaves the default host discovery phase, which may include ICMP Echo Request (Ping), but may consist of other probes depending on privilege and network location (e.g. ARP, TCP SYN, etc).

Comment: @bonsaiviking Luckily for older people like me, we appreciate the fact that they left that in the switches for scanning.  Old habits die hard.  =)  Anyway, thank you for the info and I have updated the answer.